# Azure Functions with Devops Pipelines

Tags: azure

I have pipeline and I deployed azure functions from it and I want to disable the pipeline for few days and reenable when I use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Not only azure functions you can create any pipeline, but you can also disable and re enable it whenever required*

*Under pipeline settings you can find the options of deleting the pipeline*

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfVzn.png]